# Unit and integration tests organization in .net

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

What is the best practice on organizing both Unit AND Integration tests in your solution?

I am leaning towards having 2 test projects per one actual project with naming such as `ProjectName.Tests.Unit` and `ProjectName.Tests.Integration`, however it looks like there will be too many test projects per code projects.
However the alternative is to put all tests in 2 test projects, which seems even worse.

Can someone comment how you (would) structure BOTH Unit and Integration tests in your solution?

Comment: usually I would suggest to create a test project per project. Integration test project is usually not created per project. You can create a single integration test project, or an integration test per feature that you are integration testing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As with lots of questions around *best practice*, the answer is really that it depends...

If you have lots of projects, each of which has a handful of classes that don't do very much, then having a project for integration tests and a project for unit tests for each of your projects is going to seem like overkill.

If you're writing a large-scale infrastructure that's broken down into discrete areas, sitting under services, then it may make sense to have an integration test projects for each of those services to contain the functionality and organize your tests effectively.

If your projects each represent discrete functionality that can be sensibly integration tested in isolation then it might make sense to have an integration project for each of your projects.

It really does depend on what your situation is and why you're separating the projects.

An alternative that you should consider if you aren't already doing so is using TestCategories / Traits to differentiate between your tests.  This allows you to mark up either whole test classes / fixtures or individual methods as a particular category of test (for example db integration) and then turn these tests on/off as part of your build process.

Answer (score 2):

What I used to do is creating a folder for each code project in my solution.
In this folder, I create three projects :
 1. code project
 2. integration tests
 3. unit tests

Comment: That's what I am doing and super useful.